# Finding a Pinch Map from the Given Multiplications

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is an exercise problem and I could'n know how to tackle with it and need someone's help.

Notation: Let $(A, a_{0})$ and $(X , x_{0})$ be pointed spaces, then $[A,X]_{*}$ denotes the set of all pointed homotopy classes of maps $A \rightarrow X$.

Question: Suppose $(A , a_{0})$ is a space such that for any $(X , x_{0})$

1. $[A , X]_{*}$ has a group structure
2. for each pointed map $f: (X , x_{0}) \rightarrow (Y , y_{0})$, the induced map $f_{*} : [A , X]_{*} \rightarrow [A , Y]_{*}$ is a group homomorphim.

Then prove that there is a pinch map $p : A \rightarrow A \vee A$ so that the multiplication in the group $[A , X]_{*}$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
[f][g] = [(f \vee g) \circ p].
\end{equation*}
where $[f] , [g] \in [A ,X]_{*}$ and the the multiplication between them is given by the condition 1. above.

Can someone give me a hint to start with? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let $i_1:A\hookrightarrow A\vee A$, $a\mapsto (a,\ast)$, $i_2:A\hookrightarrow A\vee A$, $a\mapsto (\ast,a)$ be the inclusion maps (we are viewing $A\vee A\subseteq A\times A$). Take $X=A\vee A$. Then by assumption the set $[A,A\vee A]$ has group structure, so define

$c=i_1+i_2\in[A,A\vee A]$

(we'll use additive notation for this product although it is not necessarily abelian). Choose a representative for this homotopy class (which we'll continue to write as $c$), and then for arbitrary maps $f:A\rightarrow X$, $g:A\rightarrow X$ consider the composition

$\nabla\circ(f\vee g)\circ c:A\rightarrow A\vee A\rightarrow X\vee X\rightarrow X$

where $\nabla:X\vee X\rightarrow X$ is the folding map. Now observe that

$\nabla\circ(f\vee g)\circ c=\nabla_*(f\vee g)_*c=\nabla_*(f\vee g)_*(i_1+i_2)=\nabla_*(f\vee g)_*i_1+\nabla_*(f\vee g)_*i_2=\nabla_*(f\vee\ast)+\nabla_*(\ast\vee g)=f+g$.

There are some steps missing, which I'll leave you to fill in (you need to show that $\ast:A\rightarrow \ast\rightarrow X$ is the unit element in $[A,X]$, for instance). If you need some more help please just let me know in a comment.

Comment: Is the $i_1$ and $i_2$ acting backwards in this line $\nabla_*(f\vee g)_*i_1+\nabla_*(f\vee g)_*i_2=\nabla_*(f\vee\ast)+\nabla_*(\ast\vee g)$? and where do we require to show that $* : A \rightarrow * \rightarrow A$?

Comment: @Happy the maps $i_1,i_2$ have been defined on the first line. For your second question you need to show that the constant map $A\rightarrow\ast\rightarrow X$ represents the unit element in the group $[A,X]$.

Comment: Yeah I see the definition of them but I do not understand if they are working backward or forward i.e., I mean if the item they act upon should be in front of them or behind them.

Comment: Why we should show that this is the unit element?

Comment: @Happy my notation is $g_\ast f=g\circ f:x\mapsto $g(f(x))$. Every group needs a unit element!